# On the Flow Blockchain what guarantees do we have on field visibility on concurrent transactions

Tags: onflow-cadence

I have been interested in thinking through a race condition in which [transactions](https://developers.flow.com/cadence/language/transactions) could be executed on the same block in non-deterministic order on the Flow Blockchain.

Let's say you have two transactions which mutate the state of a resource by calling a method on that resource.

As a contrived example:

```
pub resource Example {
   pub let flag: Bool
   ...
   pub fun flipTrue() {
      if this.flag == true {
         panic("this flag is true, we are not allowed to set it true again")
      } 
      // side effect A
      this.flag = true;
   }
   pub fun flipFalse() {
      if this.flag == false {
         panic("we are not allowed to do this if the flag is already false");
      }
      // side effect B
      this.flag = false;
   }
}
```

Let's say initially, the flag is false. Then on the same block (if this is possible), two transactions are run, one calling `flipTrue` the other `flipFalse`, let's call them FlipTrueTx and FlipFalseTx.
I am not sure how to predict what would happen here (pardon me if it is possible to build a trivial test harness for this on the emulator).

Naively, it would seem we would expect one of:

1. Something would prevent either transaction from occurring - both would panic.
2. The transactions can run in either order, and both are "visible" to the other. So the results would be non-deterministic.
3. The transactions can run in either order, and they are not visible to the other. In this case, we would only ever expect `FlipTrueTx` to run successfully, and `FlipFalseTx` would always panic.

Would be happy to provide additional information to flesh out the scenario if this isn't clear.

So far, I have attempted reading through relevant documentation and did not immediately find information on this point. I believe left to my own devices, my next step would be to attempt to test this directly. However, building a test harness might not be reliable in the emulator, and potentially quite difficult in testnet given the timing requirements. I was taking a look at the [Flow fvm design](https://github.com/onflow/flow-go/tree/master/fvm#design) to try to get a sense for how transactions within the same block were handled. If I am reading correctly, it would seem each [execution node must be processing transactions for the entire block on a single thread](https://github.com/onflow/flow-go/blob/master/engine/execution/computation/computer/computer.go#L315-L336), but would welcome confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

transactions are executed in a serial manner even if they are on the same block/same collection. This order is proposed by collection nodes and agreed upon by consensus nodes.
Assuming your flag is set to false in the init();
if `flipTrueTx` is run first, it will set the flag to `true`, then `flipFlaseTx` will set it to false.
if `flipFalse` is run first, it will panic; then `flipTrueTx` will set it to true.

you can learn more about how the blocks are assembled and the transactions are executed here: https://flow.com/primer

Comment: Thanks @rrrken -> I was taking a look at the [fvm design](https://github.com/onflow/flow-go/tree/master/fvm#design) to try to get a sense for how this was handled. If I am reading correctly, it would seem each execution node must be [processing transactions for the entire block on a single thread](https://github.com/onflow/flow-go/blob/master/engine/execution/computation/computer/computer.go#L315-L336).